# Social media logos and their bg

Tags: facebook, social-media, twitter, google-plus

I would like to change background of my website social media icons. My question is.. Is this legal? If you browse web you can find many websites that do that. For example:

Facebook "f" logo on black bg or "g+" logo on brown background...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there are some standards for each social media site since these are trademarks, however, as long as you are not changing the trademark but rather the look and feel of the image itself, I am sure you would be okay. You may want to check each one (social media site) to see what parameters exist if any and stay within these boundaries. Otherwise, you are very likely free to use social images as you please. Like you said, many sites use custom images/icons. And indeed, there are *lots* of free images/icons available. It is possible that you may see a set you like. It is worth looking around rather than making your own- unless you are a talented graphics creator.

Comment: Generally the look and feel of the logo is part of the trademark. All of the big sites provide directions of what modifications are and are not allowed.

Comment: You are right. I do know that there are boundaries, but there is also a fair amount of latitude, the limits of each, I have not researched. I advise checking out each social media site to see what the limits are. I also recommend using a set rather than *rolling your own*. It is also widely accepted that many sites create their own images/icons to match their own sites. I would not personally take on this challenge!

Comment: Facebook, Twitter, Google all have their logos trademarked. Once you make a change which they do not allow, you've infringed on their trademark and they could send their IP (Intellectual Property) lawyers after you. Though for icons I doubt they would. ie; iconfinder.com has plenty of examples of modified trademarks. They tend to go after people using their trademarks in domain names, and promotional / marketing material.

Comment: @Anagio I agree that I would not do it. Still, there is some latitude that does not effect the trademark. I assume that there are guidelines for this. I do not even want to look to be frank. There are too many image sets available. As a side note, I am not one who decorates stuff. If there are provided icons, then that is what I use! One up-vote on your comment on the way!